# SQL Query with ascending/descending output

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have the following tables which I'd like to run a query on:

Table STATE_STATS:

```
Column Name    Type     Constraint
STNAME         String
BIRTHS2010     Number
DEATHS2010     Number
REGION         Number   Foreign Key
```

I'd like to query the table to find all the states that have more births (BIRTHS2010) than deaths (DEATHS2010). I'd like to list all the states in ascending order of REGION and in the case where stats have the same region, sort them in decreasing order of BIRTHS2010. Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SELECT *
FROM STATE_STATS
WHERE BIRTHS2010 > DEATHS2010
ORDER BY REGION, BIRTHS2010 DESC
```